# Send video file from Android to desktop in AIR?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air

I'm building a mobile AIR application that connects to my desktop AIR application.
In the mobile application, I'm recording video with my Android device with **flash.media.CameraUI**.

This works perfectly, but now I'd like to send this file to my desktop application so I can do stuff with it. I've got a server written in AS3 running on my desktop (the application itself) listening to AMF messages on a certain port. I can send data through sockets, I've already tested it with accelerometer data, so that's not the issue.

What would be the best way to send video to my desktop AIR app? I've tried multiple things already; serializing using registerClassAlias, ByteArrays, ...

Any help is much appreciated, or just a push in the right direction to get me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just asked my teacher. He said I needed a way to upload it, so my PHP solution IS the best way to do it. Thanks anyway, Zárate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a [socket server](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html) on the desktop app and connecting to it from the phone, then send using a [socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html), writing and reading bytes?

J

Comment: Hi Zárate, that's exactly what I'm trying! I'm getting end of file error every time I'm reading the object, though... I'm using a temporary workaroud now, uploading every file (~350kB each) to my webserver using a PHP script and downloading again on the desktop application. This is no good solution of course. :-(